# Как перенести структуру файлов(.h .cpp) в обозревателе решений VS?

Tags: visual-studio

Каким образом можно быстро скопировать с одного решения в другое структуру папок и файлов .h .cpp в обозревателе решений?

То есть файлы заголовков и исходного кода. Вручную набирать не хочется.
Там наверняка какой то файл конфигурации лежит который можно просто скопировать.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это относится, по-моему, не к решению, а к проекту. Конфигурационные файлы в XML, вы легко сможете понять их структуру. За структуру папок(фильтров) (по крайней мере в MSVS10) отвечает файл projectName.vcxproj.filters в папке проекта, а за подцепление в проект файлов - project_name.vcxproj . Если копировать эти файлы, думаю, должно прокатить =) Само-собой, физическую структуру исходников внутри проекта также придется воспроизводить.

Comment: Нашел эти файлы. Там всё очень просто. Нужно некоторые тэги вырезать и вставить.